# Use awk to print print from a file that has a string of text with spaces

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

This is probably pretty simple, but getting errors.

I have a file formatted like:

```
6468511 node_modules aotehu
6468520 jsuno.js hello there
```

It's three columns. The last one can be any text of any length (it's a comment for that project).

I have something like the following but it only grabs the hello from the last one. How would I grab all of the text 'hello there' and save it to the var $3:

```
awk '/6468520/ {print $3}' comments
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
awk '/6468520/ {var1=$1; var2=$2; $1=$2=""; sub(/^ +/, "");
     print var1, var2, $0}' file
```

Eliminate `$1` and `$2` from `$0`. Left-trim `$0` and print

Comment: Awesmoe thanks! But I also want to keep $1 and $2 around. So I would have $1 = 6468520 $2 = filename $3 = comment.

Comment: @user2433617 either assign $1 and $2 to tempvars, like tmp1=$1 OR use tab delimited data, then $3 will have all the words. Good luck.

Comment: @user2433617, as shelter points out, you may use temp variables. See updated solution

Answer (score 1):

you can use `grep` and  `cut`:

```
grep -e ^6468520 your.file | cut -d' ' -f3-
```

`grep` will print the lines which start with `6468520` and cut will split the line by whitespaces and print from the third column to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This removes $1 and $2 and print rest.

```
awk '/6468520/ {$1=$2="";sub(/^ +/,x);print}' file
hello there
```